# sneaker is not receiving messages on heroku - RabbitMQ Bigwig

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rabbitmq, amqp, bunny

I am trying to run message queues on heroku. For this I am using **RabbitMQ Bigwig** plugin.

I am publishing messages using bunny gem and trying to receive messages with sneakers gem. This whole setup works smoothly on local machine.

I take following steps to setup queue

I run this rake on server to setup queue:

```
namespace :rabbitmq do
    desc 'Setup routing'
    task :setup_test_commands_queue do
      require 'bunny'

      conn = Bunny.new(ENV['SYNC_AMQP'], read_timeout: 10, heartbeat: 10)
      conn.start

      ch = conn.create_channel

      # get or create exchange
      x = ch.direct('testsync.pcc', :durable => true)

      # get or create queue (note the durable setting)
      queue = ch.queue('test.commands', :durable => true, :ack => true, :routing_key => 'test_cmd')

      # bind queue to exchange
      queue.bind(x, :routing_key => 'test_cmd')

      conn.close
    end
  end
```

I am able to see this queue in rabbitmq management plugin with mentioned binding.

```
class TestPublisher
  def self.publish(test)
    x = channel.direct("testsync.pcc", :durable => true)
    puts "publishing this = #{Test}"
    x.publish(Test, :persistent => true, :routing_key => 'pcc_cmd')
  end

  def self.channel
    @channel ||= connection.create_channel
  end

  def self.connection
    @conn = Bunny.new(ENV['RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_TX_URL'], read_timeout: 10, heartbeat: 10) # getting configuration from rabbitmq.yml
    @conn.start
  end
end
```

I am calling TestPublisher.publish() to publish message.

I have sneaker worker like this:

```
require 'test_sync'
class TestsWorker
  include Sneakers::Worker
  from_queue "test.commands", env: nil

  def work(raw_event)
    puts "^"*100
    puts raw_event
    # o = CaseNote.create!(content: raw_event, creator_id: 1)
    # puts "#########{o}"
    test = Oj.load raw_event
    test.execute
    # event_params = JSON.parse(raw_event)
    # SomeWiseService.build.call(event_params)
    ack!
  end
end
```

My Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
sneaker: WORKERS=TestsWorker bundle exec rake sneakers:run
```

My Rakefile

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
require 'rake'
require 'sneakers/tasks'

Test::Application.load_tasks
```

My sneaker configuration

```
require 'sneakers'
Sneakers.configure  amqp: ENV['RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_RX_URL'],
                    log: "log/sneakers.log",
                    threads: 1,
                    workers: 1

puts "configuring sneaker"
```

I am sure that message gets published. I am able to get message on rabbitmq management plugin. But sneaker does not work. There is nothing in sneakers.log that can help.

sneakers.log on heroku :

```
# Logfile created on 2016-04-05 14:40:59 +0530 by logger.rb/41212
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? One silly thing: have you assigned a dyno to sneakers process? Other than that, can you put `puts "configuring sneaker"` before the actual configuration line and see if it is displayed in logs? 
Also shouldn't your log on heroku contain info on dyno from which it is coming from?

Comment: This might help some poor soul in the future. I was doing something similar but on `cloud66`, I had to change my procfile: from `sneaker: WORKERS=TestsWorker bundle exec rake sneakers:run` to `sneaker: bundle exec rake sneakers:run WORKERS=TestsWorker ` NOTE - the WORKERS env must come at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for this late response. I was able to get this working on heroku.  When I faced this error after hours of debugging I was not able to fix it. So I rewrote all above code and I did not check what was wrong with my previous code.

The only problem with this code and correct code is queue binding.

I had two queues on same exchange. `pcc.commands` with routing key `pcc_cmd`  and `test.commands` with routing key `test_cmd`.

I was working with `test_cmd` but as per following line in `TestPublisher`

```
x.publish(Test, :persistent => true, :routing_key => 'pcc_cmd')
```

I was publishing to different queue(pcc.commands). Hence I was not able to recieve the message on `test.commands` queue.

In `TestWorker`

```
from_queue "test.commands", env: nil
```

This states that fetch messages only from `test.commands` queue.

**Regarding `sneakers.log` file:**
  Above setup was not able to give me logs in `sneakers.log` file. Yes this setup works on your local development machine, but it was not working on heroku. Now days to debug such issue I ommit `log` attribute from configuration. like this:

```
require 'sneakers'
Sneakers.configure  amqp: ENV['RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_RX_URL'],
                  # log: "log/sneakers.log",
                  threads: 1,
                  workers: 1
```

This way you will get sneaker logs (even heartbeat logs) in heroku logs which can be seen by running command `heroku logs -a app_name --tail`.